# Dask read_csv start/stop criteria

Tags: python, dask

I have a csv file with distinct headers (actually lines) inbetween

```
COMMENT1
COMMENT2
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
0 /END OF A DATA
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
0 /END OF B DATA
```

Are there hooks in read_csv() that I can use to get data between these sections? Note this is a large file on which I would like to do some statistics without loading entire file into memory

df=dask.dataframe.read_csv('datafile.csv',skiprows=3, header=None,quotechar="'")

could I load just block1 or block2 alone (again not completely into memory)?

Thanks,

Comment: Does the chunk separator always look like `"\n0 /END"...`, and is it reasonable not to expect that string anywhere else?

Comment: Yes and yes (to the extent I have seen)

Answer (score 0):

You can load your data using the function [read_bytes](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/bytes.html#dask.bytes.read_bytes) - this will read your file(s) and turn it into chunks based on an arbitrary delimiter.

```
from dask.bytes import read_bytes
sample, chunks = read_bytes(mypath, delimiter=b'\n0 /END')
```

This will produce delayed objects, where each contains *one or more* of your data blocks. You will need to come up with an appropriate function to process each chunk and return dataframes from each. Something like the following:

```
def process_chunk(data):
    blocks = data.decode().split("\n0 /END")
    out = []
    for data in blocks:
        data = '\n'.join(line for line in data.split('\n')
                     if not (line.startswith('COMMENT') or
                     line.startswith(' OF ')))
        if data:
            out.append(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), header=None))
    return out

chunks = chunks[0]  # if only one file
results = [dask.delayed(process_chunk)(ch) for ch in chunks]
```

Dask will process your data chunk-by-chunk and not load everything into
memory at once.

You can evaluate one or more elements of `results` using [`dask.compute()`](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/api.html#dask.compute), or apply more [delayed](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html) functions to them, before calling `compute()` in order to process them in parallel.

Comment: Using "results", how can I distinguish one dataframe from another?(first set of 2 rows,4 cols from secondset of 2 rows and 7 cols)?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Each element of results evaluates to one or more dataframes.

Comment: I tried  print  results[0].head() ..  prints  delayed  again. Can I   see the first   row   for testing?

Comment: Ok..here's another try: (results[0])[[1]].sum().compute()    ----TypeError: url type not understood: <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x37c9cb0>

Comment: Edited, but I didn't really want to create the processing function myself, I believe you might have had a go at that.

Comment: This time around len(results) is only 1 [delayed...].     c1=(results[0])[[0]].sum().compute() says 
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list.  len(blocks) is 3.  But the 2 "frames" did  not  seem   to go into results[0]  and results[1]. I wonder if  delimiter  of read_bytes  is  working

Comment: `(results[0])[[0]].sum()` ?? You want `dask.compute(results[0])` to evaluate the first set of dataframes (see the last paragraph). If you only have one delayed object, your data is not very big - the default chunk size is 128MB.

Comment: dask.compute(results[0]) results in ([],).  note that first frame has  4  columns  and second frame  has  7   columns. I would like  say sum  of first column in frame1  and sum of second column   in frame2.

Comment: With the data you provided, there are dataframes. Some elements of result may be empty.